# Django Datefield, TimeField, and DecimalField not displaying

Tags: django, django-forms

Hi Djangonauts,
                 I am new to Django. Please forgive any silly mistakes in code or logic

My forms are not displaying the fields like they should(See Image).

The `price` field only lets me put numbers but there is no restriction on how many numbers It even lets me add a 15 digit number

The `date` and `time_from`, `time_to` fields just show long text-input fields. What am I doing wrong?

```
class LessonsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Lessons
        fields = ('price', 'quantity', 'date', 'time_from', 'time_to')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields['quantity'].label = "How many members in one class"
       self.fields['price'].label = "How much do members have to pay to take lessons from you"
       self.fields['date'].label = "When do you plan to offer lessons"
       self.fields['time_from'].label = "What time do the lessons start"
       self.fields['time_to'].label = "What time does the lessons end"

    widgets = {
            'price': forms.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5),
            'quantity': forms.IntegerField(min_value=1, max_value=25),
            'date': forms.DateField(format("%b %d %Y")),
            'time_from': forms.TimeField(format('%H:%M')),
            'time_to': forms.TimeField(format('%H:%M'))
}
```

**Below are the models**

```
class Lessons(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    date = models.DateField()
    time_from = models.TimeField()
    time_to = models.TimeField()


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('posts:single', kwargs={'username': self.user.username,
                                               'slug': self.post.slug})
```

**Below is the image of how the form now looks**
[image]

Comment: That widgets dict won't go anything - it's in the wrong place, and anyway it's for widgets, not fields. What types are those fields in the first place? Show the model.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am sorry I have added the models in the questions above

Comment: @DanielRoseman I also tried to add the formats in the models but somehow that does not work either example `date = models.DateField(format("%b %d %Y"))`

Answer (score 1):

I know I am replying very late, but it might be helpful for someone looking for answer later.

The TimeField is loaded as "Text-input" fields because when the form is rendered we need to explicitly mention that the particular field is a Time field.

In your question you want Time to be shown as `HH:MM AM/PM` format, for which we can use Timeinput widget as:

```
widget=forms.TimeInput(format='%I:%M %p', attrs={'type': 'time'})
```

Here, through `attrs` we are explicitly defining the input type as a "Time" input.